# Does Kubernetes support VM / node provisioning & management?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud-foundry, paas

To my understanding [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io) is a container orchestration service comparable to [AWS ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) or [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/). Yet there are several [high rated questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047563/kubernetes-vs-cloudfoundry/32238148) on stackoverflow that compare it to [CloudFoundry](https://www.cloudfoundry.org) which is a plattform orchestration service.

This means that CloudFoundry can take care of the VM layer, updating and provisioning VMs while moving containers avoiding downtime. Therefore the comparison to Kubernetes makes limited sense to my understanding.

Am I misunderstanding something, does Kubernetes support provisioning and managing the VM layer too?

Comment: No it does not. It's strictly a container orchestration platform. Its API/Scheduler/ControlManager is not responsible for provisioning and managing VMs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can manage VMs with [KuberVirt](https://github.com/kubevirt) as @AbdennourTOUMI pointed out. However, Kubernetes focuses on container orchestration and it also interacts with [cloud providers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/) to provision things like Load Balancers that can direct traffic to a cluster.

[Cloud Foundry](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/overview.html) is a PaaS that provides much more than Kubernetes at the lower level. Kubernetes can run on top of an IaaS like AWS together with something like [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/)

This is a diagram showing some of the differences:

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Hello @Rico, I disagree BTW. Check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52903421/747579

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI you are right! I forgot about KubeVirt, thanks for pointing it out. I changed my answer a bit.

Comment: Great change! I liked the way that you followed to integrate both info: focusing containers orchestration+highlighting VM

Answer (score 4):

As for **VM**, my answer is **YES**; you can run VM as workload in k8s cluster.

Indeed, Redhat team figured out how to run VM in the kubernetes cluster by adding the patch [KubeVirt](https://kubevirt.io/docs/workloads/controllers/virtualmachine.html).

example from the link above.

```
apiVersion: kubevirt.io/v1alpha2
kind: VirtualMachine
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    kubevirt.io/vm: vm-cirros
  name: vm-cirros
spec:
  running: false
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        kubevirt.io/vm: vm-cirros
    spec:
      domain:
        devices:
          disks:
          - disk:
              bus: virtio
            name: registrydisk
            volumeName: registryvolume
          - disk:
              bus: virtio
            name: cloudinitdisk
            volumeName: cloudinitvolume
        machine:
          type: ""
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 64M
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
      volumes:
      - name: registryvolume
        registryDisk:
          image: kubevirt/cirros-registry-disk-demo:latest
      - cloudInitNoCloud:
          userDataBase64: IyEvYmluL3NoCgplY2hvICdwcmludGVkIGZyb20gY2xvdWQtaW5pdCB1c2VyZGF0YScK
        name: cloudinitvolume
```

Then:

```
kubectl create -f vm.yaml
virtualmachine "vm-cirros" created
```